# Divide by zero with power function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to use power function but error comes up as

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

calculation is

```
select POWER(0,-0.79)
```

Comment: This expression (zero raised to a negative power) is mathematically undefined. What would you like the outcome to be? You can have it be anything you want by checking your arguments with `CASE` first.

Comment: the calculation there is 1 / 0^.79 = 1 / 0    as well as failing for zero, it would also fail for < 0 (first number negative)

Comment: @JeroenMostert That is wrong.  A negative power is defined.

Answer (score 3):

Negative powers resolve to divisions: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110142458/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55594.html)

You need to either use something like a `CASE` statement to handle getting 0 values in your expression or make sure your source data/query logic is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Zero to any power is zero.
A negative power would go in the denominator.
1/0 is a divide by zero error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot divide 1 by zero. You can use case expression, when the exponent is negative and the denominator is ZERO, use `ABS()` transform the negative exponent to a positive value.

One more thing is that if you want to calculate `2^(-2)`, you can write `SELECT POWER(2*1.0000,-0.79)`